# Compare two strings without using functions

Tags: c, string

I have to compare two strings, and say if they are the same or not. **Be careful because here the same means : same letters but not necessary in the same order, and not necessary upper case or lower case.**

Example : Good-Luck and luCkog-od are the same (for me !). Thats what I want to do.

--

This is what I've already done:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int length, i = 0, j = 0, same=0, different=0;
    char string1[101];
    char string2[101];
    printf("Please enter the length of the two strings\n");
    scanf("%d", &length);
    getchar();

    printf("\nPlease enter the first string\n");
    while((string1[i] = getchar())!='\n')
        i++ ;
        string1[i] = '\0';

    printf("\nPlease enter the second string\n");
    while((string2[j] = getchar())!='\n')
        j++ ;
        string2[j] = '\0';

    for(i=0; i<=(length-1); i++){
            for(j=0; j<=(length-1); j++){
                if(string1[i]==string2[j] || string1[i]==string2[j] + 32 || string1[i]==string2[j] - 32){
                    same++;
                }
                if(string1[i]!=string2[j] || string1[i]!=string2[j] + 32 || string1[i]!=string2[j] - 32){
                    different++;
                }
            }

    }

    if(same>=length && different<=length*length){
        printf("\nThe two strings are the same!");
    }
    else{
        printf("\nThe two strings are not the same!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So this code works perfectly for a lot of example, but in this case :

3d-Cubes*X*Y*Z = string1

Cubes*x\Y*Z-3D = string2

It doesn't work! The program said that is the same but its not because of the \ in the second string!

--

**My questions**:

What I have to add/modify in order that my code works for examples like this too?

Is there something more simple to do? (instead of what I did (using FOR)).

P.S: Without using functions.

Comment: You can sort both arrays alphabetically and then compare.

Comment: Ok, and for comparaison, I still use FOR ?

Comment: The comparison operator is generally used for comparison.

Comment: What is `'+' + 32`? Prefer using `tolower()` (and/or `toupper()`).

Comment: Why "without using functions" ??

Comment: Since the two strings need to have: 1. Letters, 2. Case does not matter, 3. Order does not matter, you can use a lookup table of ascii codes (256-element arrays) for each string. Increment the corresponding value in the table when you encounter a character (using convoluted addition/subtraction for letters to deal with case). Then compare the lookup tables. You will get O(N) performance.

Comment: @pmg, it's for upper case.

Comment: @user: try this `if ('+' + 32 == 'K') puts("oops");`

Comment: Sorting the string character-by-character would work because then you could compare the two strings. You could keep an array of size 128 and for each character's value, use the array to sum up the number of occurrences. Then walk through the array, and the first time you encounter an odd number of occurrences (count[n] % 2 != 0), there is a mismatch. Does letter case have a role in this or not? (Is "3d" the same as "3D"?) That will affect your code.

Comment: yeah 3d is the same like 3D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only check that every character in string1 occurs in string2 and the strings are the same length.

You do not check that every character in string2 occurs in string1, so if you have any duplicate characters in string1 (e.g. the 's' in your example), you can erroneously think the strings are the same. I presume they would treat 'aab' and 'abb' the same as well.

You also treat characters that are 32 places apart as the same, but you should only do this for letters, not any other characters.

Instead you could have an int array with 256 entries for each string, and count the incidents of each character in each string (ensuring that you modify anything between 'A' and 'Z' by adding 'a' - 'A' to it, to deal with case issues, before incrementing its count in the array.

Then iterate over the arrays ensuring they are the same.

Comment: Actually we can have 128 entries since these are ascii codes now that I think about it.

Comment: Ok Ok, so I'm trying to understand this.. Thanks for the answers guys.

In fact, I have no idea how to start with this now..

Comment: @user2482551 so first of all, I have to sort alphabetically the two string character by character ? I can do this without using fonctions ?

Comment: NO you do not do any sorting. Look at what I just posted. You are keeping a count of how many times you encounter each character inside of an array, which you index by the character value you are on in the string. Essentially your lookup table maps ascii values to a count of that value in the string. Then you compare the lookup tables to see if they are equal.

Comment: "... modify ... before incrementing its count in the array." is one approach.  Another is to not modify before incrementing, but to consider case folding on the sums.  +1 for a nice approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the lookup-table based solution assuming you have them read in already. I did not test this, so the case-transform may be incorrect. You can also put both in the same loop if you want since you have equal length as a precondition:

```
char *str1; //all ready to go
char *str2; //also ready to go
int countOne[128] = {0}, countTwo[128] = {0}, ndx, equal = 1;
while (*str1) {
   if (*str1 >= 'A' && *str1 <= 'Z')
      countOne[*str1++ + 'a' - 'A']++;
   else
      countOne[*str1++]++;
}
while (*str2) {
   if (*str2 >= 'A' && *str2 <= 'Z')
      countOne[*str2++ + 'a' - 'A']++;
   else
      countOne[*str2++]++;
}
for (ndx = 0; ndx < 128 && equal; ndx++)
   equal = countOne[ndx] == countTwo[ndx];

//equal now has whether they are equal.
```

Comment: Thanks, im really trying to understand.

But in the beginning, what does that mean "all ready to go", and in my code, I have string1[101] and string2[101] (because I dont want that the user could write a string of more than 100 characters)

And I dont understand how you can write while(*str1) just like this.. I mean it gives me an error :S

Comment: I expect the "all ready to go" comments indicate that you should have set these str1 and str2 variables up to point to the strings you are interested in - so the code in this answer does not bother replicating the code you had for reading in the strings from the user (note that your original code does not prevent the user causing problems by entering strings which are more than 100 characters long, and hence causing a buffer overflow). So if you set str1 and str2 to point at your original string1 and string2 having read in the data, this should work.

Comment: OP said nothing about ASCII, so using the 128 size is a problem.  Better to use `[UCHAR-MAX+1]`.  Using `char` to form an index is problematic as the value may be negative.  The most direct solution is to convert `char *str1;` as in `unsigned char *ustr1 = (unsigned char *) str1;`.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, but the other posters are correct I was assuming you would point the pointers to a string or replicate this code as a function taking char pointer parameters. Chux, you are correct I had originally supposed he would be using basic ascii. 256 and unsigned is the way to go if you aren't guaranteed ascii op.

Comment: Dont be sorry !:) You helped a lot. I am just a noob in C :). I think its clear now!!. Thanks a lot for your help. @user2482551

Comment: Thanks mc110 and chux too !

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following code. It may help you... 
If you do not want the existing content modified, take extra variables accordingly for backup.

```
main()
{
char s[120],t[120];
int i,j,extra;
printf("enter first string:");
gets(s);
flushall();
printf("enter second string:");
gets(t);
for(i=0;s[i];i++)
{
    if(s[i]>=65&&s[i]<=90)
      s[i]+=32;
    for(j=0;t[j];j++)
    {
       if(t[j]>=65&&t[j]<=90)
         t[j]+=32;
       if(s[i]==t[j])
       {
         t[j]=1;
         break;
       }
    }
    if(!t[j])
      break;
}
for(i=extra=0;t[i];i++)
   if(t[i]!=1)
     extra++;
if(!s[i] && extra==0)
  printf("matched");
else
  printf("not matched");    
}
```